# How to convert 3D model height to centimeter

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I am using Helixtoolkit for loading STL file. In helixviewport3D scene, I calculate model height using Bounds method. Bounds method return 3D Rectangle that wraps the model. Bounds.SizeZ return model height. But I want that size in centimeter or other unit that existing in real world. I search that a little and found that 1px equals 0.026458333 cm in real. Is that correct for all viewport or computers.

How can I calculate that height?
[image]